# Avoid extra space in anchor caused by line height - flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, line-height

I have this set of boxes with links and they are displayed as flex items. The problem is that the coverage of the clickable area(yellow area) is not consistent due to the height of each box. Setting the line height of anchor tag to zero will fix the issue but that introduces other problems like overlapping text. How can I fix this issue while keeping both line height and flex behavior?

Thanks

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

a {
  background: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /*height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        one 
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        two blah blahdfdfdfdfdfdfd
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        three blah blah
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        four
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        five
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        six
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `a {height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}`

Comment: Thanks for this!

Comment: Hi Niet, I'm also trying to make the widths of the boxes to be the same. Added flex: 1 1 0 to the flex item but no change there. Any idea why? Thanks. I've updated my original code snippet to show the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;` to the `a` css

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fff;
}

a {
  background: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.3;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        one 
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        two blah blah
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        three blah blah
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        four
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        five
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        six
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Matias for the answer

Comment: Hi Matias, I'm also trying to make the widths of the boxes to be the same. Added flex: 1 1 0 to the flex item but no change there. Any idea why? Thanks. I've updated my original code snippet to show the issue.